# Nomenclature Question: Algebraic Studies

Tags: abstract-algebra

What are magmas, monoids, groups, rings,  modules, fields, algebras, etc. called? I have been calling them "algebraic structures", but I want to know their real/recognized and general name. I would prefer to exclude things not "like" them but I want to include everything that /is/ like them.

Comment: I think that *is* the general name. That's what my professors used when I was a graduate student, it's what I use now, it's what my colleagues use. If there *is* an "official" name out there, it's not universally recognized.

Comment: You may want to look at [universal algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra), in particular at [varieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)).

Comment: "Algebraic structure" seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

In your list, (almost) every example is a [variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_%28universal_algebra%29) in the sense of universal algebra. You can also call it a finitary [algebraic category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category). Objects of finitary algebraic categories may be called algebraic structures. However, there is one exception: Fields don't form a variety (for example since there are no initial objects, no coproducts, no products, etc.). In how far fields are algebraic structures has been discussed at mathoverflow [MO/3003](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3003/in-what-sense-are-fields-an-algebraic-theory). A good replacement is the algebraic category of [meadows](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0823).